# Hide files in .csproj without excluding them from build

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, visual-studio-2017, csproj

Is it possible to hide files/folders in .net core csproj without excluding them from build? I have a folder containing generated files which I would rather see they are not visible inside Solution Explorer in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can set the [`Visible="false"` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-items#content) on the items.

For an SDK-based project (.net core / asp.net core templates), you could add e.g.:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Update="**/*.css" Visible="false" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Depending on your project type (=> defaults), you might have to replace `Content` with `None` for the particular type, or even `Compile` for generated code files.

Comment: Is it possible to hide folder too? This hides all files in folder Generated, but the empty folder is still visible...

    <Compile Update="Generated\\**" Visible="false" />

Comment: To my knowledge, this is not possible. Many new tools try to autogenerate into `obj` (`$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)`) and include the items during the build and not as static ("root level") items using the `Link` metadata... But yes I also have stray `dist` / `css` folders etc.

Comment: I find that setting Visible to false means that VS will not trigger a build if one of these files changes.  https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/140935/invisible-project-items-do-not-trigger-a-build.html

Comment: Is this supposed to work with .Net Core projects? I added the `Visible` tag and the file still shows in solution explorer.

Comment: For NetCore and NetStandard It would not work for me unless I used None.

`<None Remove="**/*.asmdef" Visible="false"/> `

Comment: @CodieMorgan there is a difference between hiding files and removing them from the project. `<None Remove="..` excludes files from the project (for which you don't need a `Visible` attribute).

Comment: By me it isn't available as attribute only as an element <Visible>False</visible>

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Martin answer, I found a way to apply it to a whole folder using `**\**`. For example for an ASP.NET Core `wwwroot\Scripts` folder which contains files compiled by TypeScript (`TypeScriptCompile`):

```xml
    <ItemGroup>
        <TypeScriptCompile Update="wwwroot\Scripts\**\**" Visible="False" />
        <Content Update="wwwroot\Scripts\**\**" Visible="False" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

As his answer noted, you can add more type in there like `None`.