# Hide files with some extension (dll) in visual studio solution explorer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

I have a VS2017 solution and project which is displaying these core dll libraries in solution explorer, which pollutes the view.

[image]

The dlls are included via a .targets file included in a 3rd party nuget package. 
I know this because when I try right click item -> remove, I get error prompt:

> Cannot modify an evaluated object originating in an imported file
>   "....nuget\packages\some.third.party.package\1.0.0\some.third.party.package.targets"

Obviously, best thing to do would be to solve root problem and not include these dlls files in msbuild targets file, however let's assume I cannot remove/modify/update this 3rd party library and it is necessary to use.

How can I configure Visual Studio (2017) to not show these dlls? Some way to filter the view is a good enough fix for me.

Comment: did you [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45613251/hide-files-in-csproj-without-excluding-them-from-build)?

Comment: @Jonesopolis The library responsible for including these dll's is not in my control, it is 3rd party package

Comment: If you do something like @Jonesopolis linked to in your project file after the <Import> from the Nuget package, it should update those existing items to make them no longer visible.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I configure Visual Studio (2017) to not show these dlls? Some way to filter the view is a good enough fix for me.

To my knowledge, there is no such configure Visual Studio (2017) to hide those `dlls`. Because those files are included via a `.targets` file included in a 3rd party nuget package, we could not handle those `dll` files **directly**. In addition, you also have no control over this third party package.

So I am afraid you could not hide those `dll` files in Visual Studio 2017 without manipulating `dlls` files directly.